# Complex server logic and node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I love node.js, socket.io, the templating engines, etc: as a web framework, it's amazing.

A lot of my back-end work is with NLP, Machine Learning, and Data Mining, for which there exist hundreds of rock-solid Python libraries, but no Javascript libraries. If I were using Django, I'd just `import` the libraries and chug away.

What's the recommended approach for handling these complex tasks with node.js? Should I stick with Python web frameworks, is there a convention to dealing with these libraries, or some solution I'm missing?

Comment: node should not do heavy computation. It should create sub processes (command line) to do that for it. Node is just handling IO and doing message passing. Spawn a C process to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Stick with python to be honest. You can get the same kind of performance and style that node.js puts out using twisted.

Comment: Twisted is ew. However if you're coming from, or considering node.js, you are probably the perfect fit for twisted. Better to use the most general language for the job. Definitely dish out some sub processes if you need to do heavy CPU work, but *do not* do this unless it's a bottle neck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question. Python has greater maturity and by your own admission has the libraries you require. Could you narrow down your requirements a bit more?

Comment: Point taken, will stick with Python.